# Not able to get scanner device name via bluetooth on iOS device

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Currently working on xamarin and trying to connect a scanner device(Zebra scanner) via bluetooth. CoreBluetooth.CBPeripheral is used to get information of device like id, name etc…

To scan device used following code :

```
protected override async Task StartScanningForDevicesNativeAsync(Guid[] serviceUuids, bool allowDuplicatesKey, CancellationToken scanCancellationToken)
        {
            // Wait for the PoweredOn state
            await WaitForState(CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn, scanCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (scanCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                throw new TaskCanceledException("StartScanningForDevicesNativeAsync cancelled");

            Trace.Message("Adapter: Starting a scan for devices.");

            CBUUID[] serviceCbuuids = null;
            if (serviceUuids != null && serviceUuids.Any())
            {
                serviceCbuuids = serviceUuids.Select(u => CBUUID.FromString(u.ToString())).ToArray();
                Trace.Message("Adapter: Scanning for " + serviceCbuuids.First());
            }

            DiscoveredDevices.Clear();
            _centralManager.ScanForPeripherals(serviceCbuuids, new PeripheralScanningOptions { AllowDuplicatesKey = allowDuplicatesKey });
        }
```

And getting Response in Event by following code :

```
_centralManager.DiscoveredPeripheral += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Trace.Message("DiscoveredPeripheral: {0}, Id: {1}", e.Peripheral.Name, e.Peripheral.Identifier);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DiscoveredPeripheral: {0}, Id: {1}", e.Peripheral.Name, e.Peripheral.Identifier);;
            var name = e.Peripheral.Name;

            foreach (var oData in e.AdvertisementData)
            { 
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AdvertisementData : key : " + oData.Key + " , Value : " + oData.Value);
            }

            if (e.AdvertisementData.ContainsKey(CBAdvertisement.DataLocalNameKey))
            {
                // iOS caches the peripheral name, so it can become stale (if changing)
                // keep track of the local name key manually
                name = ((NSString)e.AdvertisementData.ValueForKey(CBAdvertisement.DataLocalNameKey)).ToString();
            }

            var device = new Device(this, e.Peripheral, name, e.RSSI.Int32Value,
                ParseAdvertismentData(e.AdvertisementData));
            HandleDiscoveredDevice(device);
        };
```

Now, in this AdvertisementData doesn’t contains CBAdvertisement.DataLocalNameKey so not able to get device name…?